# How to return Oracle query results to Rust main function?

Tags: oracle, rust

I'm using the Oracle crate to connect to an Oracle database, which works. I have created an extra function to pass the schema, uid, password and sql statement. I'm not able to have this function return a resultset.

```rust
extern crate oracle;

use oracle::{Connection, Version};

fn oracle_connect(uid: &str, pass: &str, server: &str, sql: &str) -> oracle::ResultSet<&T> {
    let client_ver = Version::client().unwrap();
    let conn = Connection::connect(uid, pass, server).unwrap();
    let (server_ver, banner) = conn.server_version().unwrap();
    let mut stmt = conn.prepare(sql, &[]).unwrap();
    let rows = stmt.query(&[]).unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    let mut sql_result = oracle_connect("test", "test", "SID", "select * from OPTIONS");
    println!("{:?}", sql_result);
}
```

errors I receive are: '^^ undeclared lifetime' or 'wrong number of type arguments'. I expect to get the  query results or rows back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors in your code. [`ResultSet`](https://docs.rs/oracle/0.3.1/oracle/struct.ResultSet.html) expects 2 generic parameters: one lifetime, and one type. [`query`](https://docs.rs/oracle/0.3.1/oracle/struct.Connection.html#method.query) returns a `oracle::Result<ResultSet<Row>>`, so your code must looks like:

```rust
use oracle::{Connection, ResultSet, Row};

fn oracle_connect(uid: &str, pass: &str, server: &str, sql: &str) -> oracle::Result<ResultSet<Row>> {
    let conn = Connection::connect(uid, pass, server)?;
    let mut stmt = conn.prepare(sql, &[])?;

    stmt.query(&[])
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still learning, especially how to read and use the external crates.Unfortunately I'm still receiving the "error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier" at ResultSet<Row>>.

Comment: That's how the return type is written in the documentation, that's strange. I cannot test the code right now, so I cannot help you anymore. I think that you cannot do the thing like that since the result set lifetime is bound to the connection lifetime.

Comment: I opened an issue in Github.

Answer (score 0):

The maintainer of the Oracle crate helped out. This code works but is inefficient.

```
use oracle::{Connection, Row};

fn oracle_connect(uid: &str, pass: &str, server: &str, sql: &str) -> 
oracle::Result<Vec<Row>> {
    let conn = Connection::connect(uid, pass, server)?;
    let mut rows = Vec::new();
    for row_result in conn.query(sql, &[])? {
        rows.push(row_result?);
    }
    Ok(rows)
}
```